# fileReader.readAsText returns a string with quote

Tags: javascript

`fileReader.readAsText` puts a pair of `double quotes` around the content of the file in the `http body`.

Is there a way to remove the `quotes`?

Comment: To remove quotes `str.substr(1, str.length-2)`. But are you sure those quotes are actually there?

Comment: As @Ibu said, are you sure they're there? Quotes are used to signify that a value is a string in most types of output, but they're not actually part of the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. In the javascript code that wrap around the func, there is a call to stringify. Problem solved.